# Run integration tests on spring-boot REST controller which required authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test-mvc

I wish to run integration test on a spring-boot rest controller which looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserProfileResource {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user-profiles", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<UserProfile> createUserProfile(@RequestBody UserProfile userProfile) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST {} request to save UserProfile : {}", getCurrentUserLogin(), userProfile);
(...)
    }

    public static String getCurrentUserLogin() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        String userName = null;
        if (authentication != null) {
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails)    {
                UserDetails springSecurityUser = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
                userName = springSecurityUser.getUsername();
            } else if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof String) {
                userName = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
            }
        }
        return userName;
    }

}
```

The security configuration where you can find that "/api" calls are required authentication is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
    .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
        .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
        .key(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getRememberMe().getKey())
    .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
        .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "CSRF-TOKEN")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/init").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/finish").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/profile-info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);

}
```

A basic test is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = JhipsterAuthenticatedApp.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = "ROLE_USER")
//@WithUserDetails("user")
public class UserProfileResourceIntTest {

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        UserProfileResource userProfileResource = new UserProfileResource();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(userProfileResource, "userProfileService", userProfileService);
        this.restUserProfileMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userProfileResource)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver).setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter)
            .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain)).build();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void createUserProfile() throws Exception {

        // Create the UserProfile
        restUserProfileMockMvc.perform(post("/api/user-profiles")
        //                .with(user("user").roles("USER"))
        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(userProfile)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
      (...)
 }
```

I cannot find the right setup to test this and have getCurrentUserLogin() returning the userName.